# What is Soft Schema?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, schema

I am a grad student currently working with Google app engine and its' Eco system. Recently I came across this term called [Soft Schema](http://www.google.com/events/io/2009/sessions/SofterSideofSchemas.html).

I have been using java for coding mostly for my application on App Engine and I am also using **JPA** to persist my data onto **Data Store** .

I have understood the concept of soft schema, but there is not enough information on web related to this topic . So my question is while persisting any data on Data Store what and all constraint we need to check(For Ex:**Primary Key Constraint,Not Null Constraint**) .

I just need a list of constraints I can possibly check to implement **soft schema** in my application .

Comment: I Just need list of constraints i need to check in soft schema .

Comment: Then don't expect a definite answer. Soft schema is not an official standard backed by a strict specification. Implement whatever you need.